# How to sum a list containing aggregate values of grouped columns using map in R

Tags: r, dictionary, dplyr

I have a lot of tally table data stored in lists. Due to the way the actual data is tabulated, some of the rows in each list need to be further aggregated.
A simplified sample data would look like this

```r
# make df
df <- list(
  x1 = tibble::tibble(
    fruits = c("apple", "orange", "banana", "pineapple"),
    n = sample(1:10, 4)
  ),
  x2 = tibble::tibble(
    fruits = c("apple", "orange", "banana", "pineapple"),
    n = sample(1:10, 4)
  )
)
df
#> $x1
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   fruits        n
#>   <chr>     <int>
#> 1 apple         4
#> 2 orange        3
#> 3 banana        2
#> 4 pineapple     1
#> 
#> $x2
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   fruits        n
#>   <chr>     <int>
#> 1 apple         8
#> 2 orange        5
#> 3 banana        7
#> 4 pineapple     6
```

In this data, we want to sum the n number of rows that contain "apple".
In the actual data situation, the labels of the rows to be summed are assigned to specific strings, such as "--".

```r
df2 <- 
df |> 
  purrr::map(\(x) {
    x |> 
      dplyr::mutate(across(1, \(i) {
        ifelse(stringr::str_detect(i, "apple"), "--", i)
      }))
  })

df2
#> $x1
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   fruits     n
#>   <chr>  <int>
#> 1 --         4
#> 2 orange     3
#> 3 banana     2
#> 4 --         1
#> 
#> $x2
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   fruits     n
#>   <chr>  <int>
#> 1 --         8
#> 2 orange     5
#> 3 banana     7
#> 4 --         6
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

So how can we sum the number of n in the rows whose fruits column is "--"?
I tried to solve this by simply applying a grouped `summarize` through `map`.
However, this approach does not yield the intended result, which is as follows

```r
df2 |> 
  purrr::map(\(x) {
    x |> 
      dplyr::summarise(across(2, \(i) {
        n = sum(n)
        .by = fruits
      }))
  })
#> Warning: Returning more (or less) than 1 row per `summarise()` group was deprecated in
#> dplyr 1.1.0.
#> ℹ Please use `reframe()` instead.
#> ℹ When switching from `summarise()` to `reframe()`, remember that `reframe()`
#>   always returns an ungrouped data frame and adjust accordingly.
#> Warning: Returning more (or less) than 1 row per `summarise()` group was deprecated in
#> dplyr 1.1.0.
#> ℹ Please use `reframe()` instead.
#> ℹ When switching from `summarise()` to `reframe()`, remember that `reframe()`
#>   always returns an ungrouped data frame and adjust accordingly.
#> $x1
#> # A tibble: 4 × 1
#>   n     
#>   <chr> 
#> 1 --    
#> 2 orange
#> 3 banana
#> 4 --    
#> 
#> $x2
#> # A tibble: 4 × 1
#>   n     
#>   <chr> 
#> 1 --    
#> 2 orange
#> 3 banana
#> 4 --
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

And I also used `reframe` according to the "Warning messages", but the output is the same as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
   map(~ .x %>% 
  group_by(across(1, ~ case_when(str_detect(.x, 'apple') ~ '--',
     TRUE ~ .x))) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), sum), .groups = 'drop'))
```

-output

```
$x1
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  fruits     n
  <chr>  <int>
1 --        12
2 banana     3
3 orange     5

$x2
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  fruits     n
  <chr>  <int>
1 --         5
2 banana     7
3 orange     4
```

---

Or with `reframe`

```
df %>%
   map(~ .x %>% 
 mutate(across(1, ~ case_when(str_detect(.x, 'apple') ~ '--',
       TRUE ~ .x))) %>%
  reframe(across(everything(), sum), .by = 'fruits'))
```

-output

```
$x1
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  fruits     n
  <chr>  <int>
1 --        12
2 orange     5
3 banana     3

$x2
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  fruits     n
  <chr>  <int>
1 --         5
2 orange     4
3 banana     7
```